# How to turn off Xcode Auto-Linking for app extension

Tags: xcode, linker, frameworks

I've been looking for a way to disable the Auto-Linking feature. I am using TwitterCore in my main app but not in the Keyboard nor in the iMessage extensions. I don't want to carry the load of linking the framework into the extensions, but auto-linking is being stubborn. The "Link Frameworks Automatically" project setting for these targets is already set to 'No' but I still receive the warning when the targets are built:

`d: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Users/user/Documents/Projects/MyApp/TwitterCore.framework/TwitterCore', framework linker option at /Users/user/Documents/Projects/MyApp/TwitterCore.framework/TwitterCore is not a dylib`

So other than the setting that should tell Xcode not to auto-link, is there another way to make it ignore this framework? Do I need to put it in a separate place other than with the rest of the frameworks and modify the framework search path for the main app for frameworks that are not used in extensions?

TIA,
Mike
p.s. I already looked at many of the replies to other auto-link related issues but they all address the problem from the standpoint of getting the libs to link. In my case I don't want them to link.

**Update** added in the name of the setting for auto-link and the p.s.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: I've recently updated to Xcode 9.3 and the warnings have gone away. Apparently the issue has been resolved. I haven't gone the extra step of opening up the packages to see if they're in there. That project is currently on the back burner.

Comment: That's good news, thanks! Hopefully we'll be ready to make that update as well soon.